# React native "FATAL ERROR: v8::ArrayBuffer::NewBackingStore Allocation failed" when importing amplify or auth

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, expo, aws-amplify

I'm trying to build an app by using React Native and expo. For my navigation I use expo router. Now, for authentication and database, I implemented a logic using AWS amplify. (Worked with this video:https://www.youtube.com/live/lZiVGr1lef0?feature=share&t=1860) While building this logic, everything worked perfectly, until I reloaded the app/emulator. It took me hours to find out, that every single one of these imports:

```
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify"; 
    
import { Authenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react-native"; 
    
import { DataStore } from "aws-amplify";
```

is causing this error:

```
[6408:0973D6D8] 45081 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 350.5 (396.1) -> 350.5 (367.9) MB, 248.0 / 0.0 ms (average mu = 0.819, current mu = 0.001) external memory pressure; GC in old space requested [6408:0973D6D8] 45317 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 350.5 (367.9) -> 350.5 (367.9) MB, 236.4 / 0.0 ms (average mu = 0.682, current mu = 0.001) external memory pressure; GC in old space requested 
<--- JS stacktrace ---> 
FATAL ERROR: v8::ArrayBuffer::NewBackingStore Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

What could be the reason?
I already noticed, that this only happened, when i tried to start the app in the android emulator (android studio) and didnt when opening the app with the expo app on my real ios phone.

I expected no error.